# How can I reference a specific column of a selected object in a VBA listbox?

Tags: vba, userform, listboxitem

I have a listbox compiling information from a worksheet onto a userform. I am trying to figure out how to use the value of a column from the selected object on the listbox.
For instance, this is my listbox: [image]

I want to get the value in the phone column from a selected row to plug into an xlookup code I already have written:
`SalesForm.BHSDTAPNAMELF.Value = Application.XLookup(Val(*value from selected row*), Worksheets("MASTER").Range("S:S"), Worksheets("MASTER").Range("T:T"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the MultiSelect property of the listbox is set to fmMultiSelectSingle, you can use the Column property of the listbox to return the value from the specified column of the selected row.

Therefore, since the phone column is the 7th column, and since the column indexing starts at 0, you can retrieve the desired value as follows...

```
Dim selectedItem As String
selectedItem = UserForm1.ListBox1.Column(6)
```

Actually, you can use the Me keyword to refer to the userform...

```
Dim selectedItem As String
selectedItem = Me.ListBox1.Column(6)
```

Change the name of the userform and listbox accordingly.

Comment: Nice! This is actually working a bit. However, I am getting a type mismatch error on certain items when using this: `Private Sub PopoutLeadListBox_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
Dim selectedItem As String
selectedItem = Me.PopoutLeadListBox.Column(11)

SalesForm.BHSDTAPNAMELF.Value = Application.XLookup(Val(selectedItem), Worksheets("MASTER TAPS").Range("S:S"), Worksheets("MASTER TAPS").Range("T:T"))`

Comment: Which line is giving you a type mis-match error?

Comment: What type of data does `Me.PopoutLeadListBox.Column(11)` contain?

Comment: Nevermind mate! my formula was simply hooked to the wrong table lol. Simple mistake. Your solution worked wonderfully.